# Trying to add values in python but comes up with int not callable error

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, int

I am trying to add multiple integers from a class in python however it comes up with the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "G:/documents/Computing/Python/Fighter Game.py", line 53, in 
>           if player.health() + player.strength() + player.defence() + player.speed() == 350:
>       TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

The code for the class is:

```
class Fighter:
    name = "Not Set"
    alignment = "Not Set" #good / bad
    health = 0
    strength = 0
    defence = 0
    speed = 0
    def name(self):
        return self.name
    def alignment(self):
        return self.alignment
    def health(self):
        return self.health
    def strength(self):
        return self.strength
    def defence(self):
        return self.defence
    def speed(self):
        return self.speed
    def set_name(self, new_name):
        self.name = new_name
    def set_alignment(self, new_alignment):
        self.alignment = new_alignment
    def set_health(self, new_health):
        self.health = new_health
    def set_strength(self, new_strength):
        self.strength = new_strength
    def set_defence(self, new_defence):
        self.defence = new_defence
    def set_speed(self, new_speed):
        self.speed = new_speed
```

and the code that throws up the error is:

```
player = Fighter()
while True:
    player.set_name(input("Enter your name: "))
    player.set_alignment("good")
    player.set_health(int(input("Enter your health: ")))
    player.set_strength(int(input("Enter your strength: ")))
    player.set_defence(int(input("Enter your defence: ")))
    player.set_speed(int(input("Enter your speed: ")))
    if player.health() + player.strength() + player.defence() + player.speed() == 350:
        print("Player setup complete.")
        break
    else:
        print("Numerical player values must all add up to 350.")
```

Any help that could be given would be appreciated! :-)

Comment: `.health` can't be both a property and a method. You're overwriting the method with a number when you `set_health`.

Comment: You are using defence both as an attribute and as a function (def defence(self). Rename the function or the attribute and it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two things that are called `self.health`; an integer and a method. This doesn't make sense.

Instance variables are often prefixed with `_`, and set up in `__init__()`, at least this is the "old-school" simple way of doing it:

```
def __init__(self):
  self._health = 40

def health(self):
   return self._health
```

And so on. But do look into attributes and properties for more elegant ways of doing this.

Comment: And really, since the setters and getters are doing absolutely nothing, you may as well use plain attributes...